# line break in google chart api

Tags: google-visualization

I am using google map chat api to create a image .I am generating following url
[googlechartapi](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bb%7Chelo%20world%20by%20qwerty%20%7Cff0000%7C000000)

[image]

This is the image i am getting.
But i want "by qwerty" in another line.
I tried to insert 
 or | but it is not working.
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like that I guess :

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_texts_big&chld=bb|ff0000|000000|hello+world|by+qwerty

Take a look at the [multi-line bubble documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons?hl=pl-PL#bubbles).

The first line will be always larger, and it seems you can't do anything for that.

> One or more lines of text, for multi-line text bubbles. Each line is separated by a | mark. The first line will be shown larger and boldface. Spaces must be replaced by +.

Answer (score 0):

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=FFCC33|16|h|FF0000|b|Hello+world|by+qwerty

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_texts_big&chld=bb|FFB573|000000|Helo+world|by+qwerty

[image: a hello world]

explanation:

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons?hl=pl-PL#single_line_outlined_text_icon

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons?hl=pl-PL#bubbles
?